# A good rich text control for Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, formatting, documents, richtext

I'm looking for a good rich text control for Silverlight. The one on codeplex seems to be out of date and another free one I saw on vectorlight doesn't seem to save as RTF (it uses custom xml) or doesn't have printing capabilities.

I'm thinking about dishing out some bucks for the Telerik, ComponentOne, or DevExpress rich text control, which all seem to be expensive because they are bundled.

If anyone has a recommendation on the above products or another that would be very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: I need one, too.  I also want RTF output and I'd like just to be able to get the text (without formatting) for search purposes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*[Full Disclosure: I work for Telerik.]*

Rich text editing support in Silverlight is a challenge at the moment due to limits in the Silverlight plug-in. The plug-in does not yet expose a good way to work with rich text, and it also lacks any support for printing. These are features that the core SL plug-in team are working on, so I expect that by late this year, early next we'll have a plug-in much more capable of supporting rich text editing.

In the mean time, Telerik does have a basic rich text editor for manipulating HTML. We rely on the Silverlight DOM integration to provide rich HTML editing support in Silverlight, but it is a good itermediate solution, espeically if your text is HTML formatted. Details: [RadEditor for Silverlight](http://www.telerik.com/products/silverlight/editor.aspx)

Longer term, you can expect to see a complete rich text editor from Telerik that will leverage Silvelright's native editing APIs (when they are eventually added to the plug-in). We think these enhancements are around the corner, so we're waiting for that instead of jumping the gun with a proprietary rich text editing layer that will be quickly rendered obsolete by the framework.

Hope that helps clarify the Silverlight rich text editing / printing picture today.

You can check out the requests for RTF support in Silverlight 4 in this Silverlight.net forum thread:[Silverlight 4 Wishlist](http://silverlight.net/forums/p/102856/281941.aspx)

Comment: Longer term Silverlight is not going to provide any new editing APIs so you will have to wait longer, if not indefinite.