# Silverlight Rich text box control

Tags: silverlight, richtextbox, custom-controls

Our team decided that we need our own custom Rich text box control for Silverlight app we are developing. We looked at existing controls mentioned at [A good rich text control for Silverlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372038/a-good-rich-text-control-for-silverlight)
but decided to build our own,due to varios reasons. We are planning to build it in stages, with elementary functionality in 1st stage which mainly includes text formatting. There are very big differences in our team on its estimate, as we don't have prior experience on wpf or silverlight technology.

Can you please help with guesstimates on how long it might take to build such a control, e.g. with the functionality provided by vectorlight or ComponentOne's rich text controls?

EDIT: To make question less vague:)- in 1st stage we plan to mainly add - text editing, styling, formatting, text flow, undo-redo, columns, lists.

Comment: Weird! Your team has decide its best to build your own without first having any idea how long its likely to take and therefore how much its likely to cost.  What are the "reasons" which has lead to this extraordinary choice?

Comment: As one whose heart has been broken by 3rd party libraries, I understand at least in part the "why" although I agree it could wind up being a poor choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A really long time. Building a fully-featured text edit control is one of those things like writing your own build system, that might look simple but is in fact extremely difficult, when you get into internationalization.

Answer (score 3):

It may be quicker to wait and use Silverlight 4 and its Rich Text Control, it supports most of the common Rich Text functions - and supports control hosting so would allow some custom additions it if needed.